# Старые ответы низкого качества

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок

Только что прилетело из очереди проверок об удалении ответа, содержащего только ссылку. Ответ дан 4 года назад и ссылки умерли...

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/131300/Прием-сообщений-через-tcp](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/131300/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-tcp)

С одной стороны, решение по ссылкам что в моем ответе, что в принятом ответе (там тоже ссылка и тоже мертвая) есть. И есть оно в качестве большой статьи. С другой стороны, проверяющие рекомендуют удалять такие ответы.

1. ссылка мертва, но archive.org никто не отменял (информацию по редким проблемам и вопросам приходится искать возможно и по мертвым ссылкам тоже, зависит от важности вопроса и распространенности возможных решений).
2. если в проверку попадают такие старые вопросы/ответы, проверяющие должны учитывать и срок давности и то, что удалив такой ответ, сообщество лишится части знаний. 719 просмотров конкретно у этого вопроса.
3. необходимо также учитывать, что привести такой ответ к текущим стандартам качества у ответившего может не быть ни времени, ни возможности.

Answer (score 7):

Сами вопросы при этом не удаляются, так что (2) не совсем применимо.

Собственно, переход rsdn.ru -> rsdn.org + непонятки с миграцией rsdn.org (он пару дней просто лежал) показывают, что ответы ссылки - это зло.

Archive.org - это хорошо, но только по действительно редким проблемам.

Не уверен, можно ли к таким отнести TCP в 1C. Даже если является - то те 700 человек, которые пришли в вопрос с такой же проблемой должны:

- сходить по ссылке
- удержаться от соблазна уйти в гугл в поисках более доступного ответа
- сходить на вики. узнать что rsdn.ru переехал
- сходить на rsdn.org, узнать что тот лежит
- узнать (откуда-то) об archive.org
- может быть найти решение на archive.org

Из 700 квест пройдут единицы.

При этом 99% вопросов, получивших ответы-ссылки, редкими не являются:

- [Скачивание файла](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/68293/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0/)
- [Как нарисовать линию в Visual Studio](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/166879/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-visual-studio/167151#167151)
- [Какой алгоритм лучше всего использовать для поиска в тексте?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/159793/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5/287954#287954)
- [Доступ к полю или свойству по имени](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/110439/%D0%94%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8)

... тысячи их

Нет никакого смысла оставлять в них ответы, состоящие из одной лишь мертвой ссылки.

---

Очередь низкокачественных ответов не обязательно подразумевает удаление. Никто не мешает проверяющему сходить на archive.org, выдрать оттуда содержимое и скопировать в ответ. Это лучше, чем сводить SO к каталогу мертвых ссылок и заставлять сотни заинтересованных людей искать ответы на archive.org.

Comment: "...не обязательно подразумевает..." - это, извините, туфта. Кнопка "рекомендовать удаление" да еще за компанию отлично жмется и люди идут за роботом или доброжелателем, который отфильтровал "rsdn" на data.stackexchange.com, бэджики и все такое... В итоге, по большому счету (после полутора лет ru.SO) уже можно открыто говорить о `delete from posts where creationDate<"1е апреля 2015"`. В принципе, для читающих между строк, ваш ответ до этого запроса можно и сократить.

Comment: @YuraIvanov удалить всегда проще. особенно если выбор стоит между "удалить битую ссылку" и "потратить время, которое пожалел даже тот, кто 4 года назад постил ссылку". Вы не стали переносить суть решений по ссылке даже для своего поста. Странно ожидать что кто-то будет активно делать это для чужих ответов.

Comment: 1. Я не сомневаюсь,  что и вам и другим проще.  Об этом и был пост,  перечитайте. 2. На выборах вы говорили несколько по-другому. 3. Вы сейчас предложили мне провести ревизию всех моих 750 ответов и "потрудиться"? Как мило. Извините,  но мне не удастся угнаться за проверяющими, даже если бы я последовал вашему призыву и все ответы за почти пять лет начал причесывать. 4. Я вас понял прекрасно и нисколько не удивлен ни тому что ваш ответ единственный ни тому, что вас поддерживают другие участники.

Comment: @YuraIvanov причем тут я и остальные и причем тут 750 ваших ответов? Ответ по ссылке удалили лично вы. Почему вы считаете что я должен был править исправить ответ (вот прямо обязан!), а вы - нет? Ваше время ценнее моего?

Comment: @YuraIvanov в развернутом виде: 1. И вам проще, судя по вашим действиям. 2. За оживление ответов ссылок выступал qwertiy. меня больше напрягало закрытие всего подряд, с моментов выборов я почти не закрываю вопросы. 3. Нет. я предложил вам исправить один ваш ответ, который вы почему-то удалили. 4.1 Судя по всему, не поняли. Мой ответ тут единственный, т.к. всем остальным на самом деле *все равно*. Никого не возмутило удаление древней битой ссылки. archive.org - нереальный аргумент. никто из посетителей не станет копать архив ради неуникальной темы. Для отстальных такие ответы - просто мусор.

Comment: Мой ответ удален усилиями проверяющих. А "почему-то удалили" именно вы и притом принятый ответ. Типа он мешает лично вам...

Comment: @YuraIvanov хм, сорри, похоже движок чуть по-другому стал показывать пользователя, который удалил сообщение. Раньше при удалении из очереди явно писалось что сообщение удалено духом. Теперь - на вид неотличимо от удаления автором.

Comment: @YuraIvanov Я удалил принятый ответ именно из-за битой ссылки. "не является ответом" на старых сообщениях с > 0 голосов после прохождения очереди падают модераторам. И висят там до тех пор пока модер или не удалит пост (обидев того, кто когда-то запостил ссылку) или не скажет "выглядит ок" (обидев того, кто поставил тревогу, и тех, кто голосовал в очереди). Т.е. любой + на сколь угодно ужасном ответе за 4 года - и ответ будет удален именно модератором, а не просто проверяющими. Это не означает, что модераторы злые. Просто особенность движка.